# how to change SQL xml encoding in stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, encoding

`sp_xml_preparedocument` accepts an local variable declared as `varchar(max)` and set to xml received without xml declaration.

Default encoding is then set to UTF-8 I suppose.

When I try to change it to something like UTF-16 message

> Switch from current encoding to
>   specified encoding not supported.

If I leave it on default message

> An invalid character was found in
>   text content.

is shown.

Any suggestion?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

> varchar(max)

to

> nvarchar(max)

and it works now...